# How to access data from a tsv file with multiple lines

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some issues accessing data from a tsv file. the data is on the 3rd row of the tsv. I want to access the name and print in on screen.

```
box1.bar1   box1.bar2   box1.bar3   box1.bar4   box1.total
60.0%   80.0%   40.0%   60.0%   80.0%
box1.bar1.name  box1.bar2.name  box1.bar3.name  box1.bar4.name  
name1   name2   name3   name4
```

This is my javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
  url: 'somefile.csv',
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "text",
  mimeType: "text/plain",
  success: function (data) {
   var lines = data.split(/\n/);
   var line1 = lines[0].split(/\,/);
   var line2 = lines[1].split(/\,/);
   var data = {};
   for(var i=0; i<line1.length; i++) {
    data[line1[i].trim()] = line2[i].trim();
   }
   $(".score-text").each(function( index, value ) { 
          value.innerText = data['box'+(index+1) + '.total'];
      });
      $(".data").each(function( index, value, name ) {  
          var boxIndex = Math.floor(index/4);
          var boxName = Math.floor(index/4);
          width = data['box'+(boxIndex+1) + '.bar'+(index+1-boxIndex*4)];
          console.log(data['.box'+(boxIndex+1) + '.bar'+(index+1-boxIndex*4) + '.name']);
          value.style.width = width;
      });
  }
 }); 
});
```

Comment: You can give a try for it http://papaparse.com/demo

Comment: I can access the % but having issues accessing the name and print it on screen. Don't need to use any libraries

Comment: What the first code block is? The csv file? The desired output?

Comment: That is the csv file

Comment: I guess technically that's a tsv - tab separated, not comma separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will give you 3rd row in TSV.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'somefile.csv',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "text",
                mimeType: "text/plain",
                success: function(data){
                    var lines = data.split("\n");
                    console.log(lines[2]); // logs "box1.bar1.name  box1.bar2.name  box1.bar3.name  box1.bar4.name"
                    var names = lines[2].split("\t");
                    console.log(names); //logs ["box1.bar1.name", "box1.bar2.name", "box1.bar3.name", "box1.bar4.name"]
                }
            });
        });
```